# Is it possible to pre-evaluate a value in bash's PS1?

Tags: git, bash

I'm trying to build a Bash prompt which will have both my git branch information (using __git_ps1 from git's bash-completion) and a little colored smiley to indicate whether the most recently run command was successful.

The smiley is created using this technique, which I found here on SO:

```
SMILEY="${GREEN}:)${COLOR_NONE}"
FROWNY="${RED}:(${COLOR_NONE}"
STATUS_EMOTICON="if [ \$? = 0 ]; then echo \"${SMILEY}\"; else echo \"${FROWNY}\"; fi"
```

Here's the prompt line I want to use:

```
export PS1="[\t]${RED}[\u@$MACHINE:${BOLD_CYAN}\w${GREEN}\$(__git_ps1 ' %s')${RED}]${COLOR_NONE} \`${STATUS_EMOTICON}\`\n$ "
```

Unfortunately, it looks like the programs that are run by __git_ps1 override the `$?` value, and I end up with every emoticon being a green smiley, even after running `false`.

Taking out the __git_ps1 call...

```
export PS1="[\t]${RED}[\u@$MACHINE:${BOLD_CYAN}\w${RED}]${COLOR_NONE} \`${STATUS_EMOTICON}\`\n$ "
```

...makes the emoticon work correctly.

So what I apparently need to do is evaluate `${STATUS_EMOTICON}` *before* running `__git_ps1`, but include the evaluated value *after* `__git_ps1`'s output. Is that possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't put `$(cmd)` or `` `cmd` `` directly in your `PS1`. Instead, use Bash's `PROMPT_COMMAND` var. What I usually do is define a function `_PS1_cmd` and set `PROMPT_COMMAND=_PS1_cmd`. Then in `_PS1_cmd`, I set misc vars I'd like to include in `PS1`. For example:

```
THE-OLD-PROMPT # cat prompt.rc
function _PS1_cmd()
{
    local saveExit=$?

    # This non-zero exit will not affect $? on command line
    g_git_ps1=$( echo TESTING; exit 1 )
    if (( saveExit )); then
        g_smiley=':('
    else
        g_smiley=':)'
    fi

    # Seems like this is not necessary, at least with bash 4.2.37. But
    # to be safe, always return it.
    return $saveExit
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=_PS1_cmd
PS1='$g_git_ps1 $g_smiley '
THE-OLD-PROMPT # source ./prompt.rc
TESTING :) ( exit 123 )
TESTING :( echo $?
123
TESTING :) echo $?
0
TESTING :)
```

Comment: This is great! I just had one odd problem, though. Since my emoticon is color-coded, I was seeing a ton of escape codes around it when my prompt was displayed. I tried a ton of different strategies to fix that, but I ultimately had to go back to using the original `\\`${STATUS_EMOTICON}\\`` piece in the PS1 itself. I changed `STATUS_EMOTICON` to evaluate based on the saved exit code from _PS1_cmd, though, so now the whole thing works as I intended.