# bash resolving variables in literal value for PS1

Tags: bash, literals, ps1

Attention : do not offer more simple solution for that example case, it is generated only to show a problem, order is taken from real [problem](https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt/issues/6).

I try to change my PS1 in ".bashrc", do not want to print here whole code(but do need storing template in literal before it internal variables are defined), problem summarize to:

```
PROMPT_START='$PathShort'
PathShort="\w"
PS1="$PROMPT_START$"
```

Result I have:

```
\w$
```

but I expect:

```
~/java/git/shell$
```

but if make PS1 like:

```
PS1="\w$"
```

Result will be as expected:

```
~/java/git/shell$
```

How can make PS1 by my(first) variant with postponed variable($PathShort) resolving?

Attention: I can not change order of that variables, this question is result of this [problem](https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt/issues/6)

Comment: After `$PathShort` is expanded to `\w` bash would not expand the resulted `\w` again.

Comment: can I evaluate variables in literal string, to define variable that will contain '\w' and PS1 will just do one-step expansion of '\w' to exact value ?

Comment: I don't quite understand your real problem but you could use `PROMPT_COMMAND` to do almost anything you want. Here's [one simple example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15673542/900078) I've written.

Answer (score 0):

it's not clear, do you want `\w$` in PS1? then use `PS1="\\\w$"`. When bash reads the string, it's reading the `\` as an escape character. So you need to provide a literal `\` by putting another escape character before it.  read this, it's fun :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome

Comment: thanks for pointing to problem, I updated question - I need path in prompt.

Comment: okkk,, you can check this nice link :) http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/bash-shell-ps1-10-examples-to-make-your-linux-prompt-like-angelina-jolie/   there will be many more modifications possible, just throw it to google and google will come up with anything you want

Comment: In the first 3 lines of your example, can you try echoing $PS1 after you have executed them? then you'll see what exactly is being set to PS1. Then replace the `'` with `"` and then again see what's happening.. Don't forget to let us know

Answer (score 0):

**.profile:**

```
function prompt() {
   print $PathShort
}
export -f prompt
PS1='`prompt`$ '
```

**result:**

```
alevin $ . .profile
$ export PathShort=one
one$ export PathShort=two
two$ export PathShort=three
three$
```

Comment: I need to resolve variable that store other variable (evaluate of PROMPT_START again after PathShort is edfined), in your answer you simply can do PS1='$PathShort$ '