# Change last character's color of PS1v promt based on exit status of previous command

Tags: bash, prompt, ps1

I've customized my .bashrc settings similar to default's PS1 settings from Clear Linux.
My file contents these lines:

```
EXIT="$?"
BLUE="\[\e[38;5;39m\]"
RED="\[\e[31m\]"
ORANGE="\[\e[38;5;208m\]"
WHITE="\[\e[0m\]"
    if [ "$EXIT" = "0" ]; then
          endchar="${BLUE}\\$""$WHITE"
    else
          endchar="${RED}\\$""$WHITE"
    fi
    
    if [ "$UID" = "0" ]; then
          username="${RED}\u${WHITE}"
    else
          username="${BLUE}\u${WHITE}"
    fi  

host="${ORANGE}\H${WHITE}"
dir="${BLUE}\w${WHITE}"
PS1="${username}@${host} ${dir} ${endchar} "
```

The file is sourced with no errors on login or opening new terminal windows, with one exception:
Last character in resulting PS1 string remains forever blue, though i type mistakes on terminal.

Expected behaviour of my settings is that prompt's last character $ turns red when exit status of previous command is greater than 0.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15673140/is-it-possible-to-pre-evaluate-a-value-in-bashs-ps1

Comment: Note that questions about configuring your interactive environment, as opposed to about _writing software_, are generally more appropriate at our sister site [unix.se]. Specifically, https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic calls for questions to be _unique to software development_; whereas PS1 isn't used by noninteractive shells at all!

Answer (score 1):

Add this color code to the end

```
DEF='\e[0m' #Default color and effects
PS1="${username}@${host} ${dir} ${endchar}$DEF "
```

And take a look [here](https://github.com/vaniacer/bash_color)

Comment: the fist line in OP: `EXIT="$?"` -- this'll cause it not to work at all.

Answer (score 1):

Just give you another example:

```
function _ps1_command()
{
    local rcode=$?

    if (( rcode )); then
        g_prompt_color=$'\e[1;31m'
    else
        g_prompt_color=$'\e[0m'
    fi
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=_ps1_command
PS1='[\w] \[$g_prompt_color\]\$\[\e[0m\] '
```

---

[image]